# DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker "Task invokehandler could not be chained"

Tags: coldfusion, quartz-scheduler, coldfusion-10

With scheduled tasks, but none that are chained, I get the below error in my exception.log when starting Adobe ColdFusion 10 services (on Windows). How do I troubleshoot this back to the source of the error?

```
"Error","DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2","09/15/14","15:12:02",,"Task invokehandler could not be chained"
java.lang.Exception: Task invokehandler could not be chained
    at coldfusion.scheduling.CronTask.onCompleteTask(CronTask.java:214)
    at coldfusion.scheduling.CronTask.execute(CronTask.java:130)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
```

Note: I get three nearly identical errors the only difference is where it says "Worker-2" in the error above, I also get "Worker-1" and "Worker-3"

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you could do here. You could write a ColdFusion page that checks the health of your scheduled tasks and monitor that page manually ([Check health of scheduled tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3971461/1636917)). Of course that code could also be a scheduled task itself. Or you can add logging to your scheduled task(s) at various points to "see" what they are doing. I prefer the latter.

For the simplest of logging you can check the "Enable Logging for Scheduled Tasks" in the ColdFusion administrator, under the Logging Settings Page. This will create a new log file named *scheduler.log*. This option will report when a task is started, when it ends, if it errors, etc. **BUT** this log still only contains generic information such as the task's name and the thread name used to execute the task. This in itself probably won't help you much but it will show you which thread is running which task.

For more detailed information you will need to add your own logging within your scheduled task(s) code. I typically place the logging code at main points during the code's execution; "started", "retrieving data", "updating database", "writing file", "done", etc. Then whenever you need to check what happened with the task you just read your log file to have a look.

Here is some sample code:

```
<cftry>
    <cflog file="your_file_name" type="information" text="Starting scheduled job xyz">

    ... code ...

    <cflog file="your_file_name" type="information" text="Step 123">

    ... code ...

    <cflog file="your_file_name" type="information" text="Step 456">

    ... code ...

    <cflog file="your_file_name" type="information" text="Scheduled job xyz finished successfully">

    <cfcatch type="any">
        <cflog file="your_file_name" type="error" text="Error: #cfcatch.Type#, #cfcatch.Message#, #cfcatch.Detail#">
        <!--- I usually send an email to myself for errors as well using <cfmail ... /> --->
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

And here is a link to the [documentation for the `<cflog>` tag](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cflog).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, Miguel-F. While this is a really useful tip in general, I'm not really convinced this addresses the issue though. The problem is that when the server is initialized, it throws these errors into the exception.log. The exceptions pertain to not being able to chain tasks, though none of the tasks are configured as chained.

Comment: This answer was not intended to address your issue. It is simply a means to add logging to your tasks in order to see where/if the tasks are executing. In the hopes that will shed some light on the issue or at least what task is causing the issue. If you already have logging within your tasks then you can disregard. That was not clear from your original post.

Answer (score 1):

I found the same error for *Task invokehandler could not be chained* in exception logs after performing an upgrade to a newer ColdFusion version using the migration wizard.  This appears to have been caused by the insertion of the text *invokehandler* during Scheduled Tasks import.

Remedy this behavior with the following steps:

1. Log in to the ColdFusion Administrator
2. **Edit each scheduled task** (click the pencil icon) and perform the following:

   1. Scroll down and click **Show Advanced Settings**
   2. Remove the text *invokedhandler* from the **On Complete** field
   3. Click **Submit**

The errors should cease at this point after editing all your scheduled tasks.

Comment: Thanks @Brendan, I no longer work where this was relevant, but I'll make sure they're aware of your update in case they're still beating their heads against this wall :)